# Searching in collection of tuple - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

> Here is my data :-

```
CREATE TABLE collect_things(k int PRIMARY KEY,n set<frozen<tuple<text, text>>>);

INSERT INTO collect_things (k, n) VALUES(1, {('hello', 'cassandra')});

CREATE INDEX n_index  ON collect_things  (n);
```

> Now I have to query like this :-

```
SELECT * FROM collect_things WHERE n contains ('cassandra')  ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

> Output :-

```
 k | n
---+---------
```

> Expected output :-

```
k | n
---+---------
 1 | {('hello', 'cassandra')}
```

I want to fetch my data with 'cassandra' value . Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Tuple inside Collection must be define as frozen.

> A frozen value serializes multiple components into a single value. Non-frozen types allow updates to individual fields. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen type as a blob. The entire value must be overwritten.

You must treat frozen as a single value and you can't separate them. So when querying provide the complete frozen tuple `('hello', 'cassandra')`.

```
SELECT * FROM collect_things WHERE n CONTAINS ('hello', 'cassandra');
```

If you have the data :

```
 k | n
---+---------------------------------------------
 1 | {('hello', 'cassandra'), ('test', 'seach')}
 2 |                         {('test', 'seach')}
```

Output :

```
 k | n
---+---------------------------------------------
 1 | {('hello', 'cassandra'), ('test', 'seach')}
```

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html